# How to create the NLS.LC.CTYPE

Tags: universe, u2, unidata

How do one create the NLS.LC.CTYPE file on Universe on Unix AIX?  I searched the BasicRef and BasicExt but don't see any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

The NLS.LC.CTYPE file is part of NLS (National Language Support) package in UniVerse.  You will need to install NLS as well as turn it on if you want to run in NLS mode.

The manual you are looking for is:
Rocket UniVerse NLS Guide

Note that there is no need to create the file if you are not using NLS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the manual: http://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20/universe/11.2.3/nls.pdf